# react bootstrap checkbox issue

Tags: checkbox, react-bootstrap

Using react-bootstrap, I want a checkbox on my form to be checked when my 'inactive' value is true; and not when it's false. So I set the checked attribute to this pretty straightforward line:

```
checked={inactive}
```

But I get this error when I click the checkbox: *"Warning: Received the string `false` for the boolean attribute `checked`. The browser will interpret it as a truthy value. Did you mean checked={false}?"*

Here's the relevant code:

```
render() {
  const {
    inactive,
    ...
  } = this.state;

  return (
    <Form.Group as={Row}>
      <Form.Label>Inactive<Form.Label>
      <Col>
        <Form.Check
          type="checkbox"
          checked={this.state.inactive}
          onChange={() => {
            if (inactive === 'false') {
              this.setState({ inactive: 'true' });
            } else {
              this.setState({ inactive: 'false' });
            }
          }}
        />
      </Col>
    </Form.Group>
    );
  } 
}
```

So then I changed the checked attribute to the following. But in this case, the the value does not get set correctly when false:

```
...
      checked={inactive === 'true'}
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your state is this:

```
state={
inactive:false,
....
}
```

Remove this object de-structuring:

```
const {
    inactive,
    ...
  } = this.state;
```

and make changes as this

```
 <Form.Check
          type="checkbox"
          checked={this.state.inactive}
          onChange={() => {
            this.setState({ inactive: !this.state.inactive });
          }}
        />
```

I hope this helps!

[See this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-m9pbx)

Answer (score 0):

you state needs to be :

```
this.state = {
          inactive: false
}
```

and remove this object destructuring:

```
const {
inactive,
...
} = this.state;
```

Another optimization to avoid if-else...

```
onChange={()=>this.setState({
    inactive: !this.state.invactive
)}
```